# SQL Server - Find Max DateTime in list of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the max date in my sysobjects tables that have a datatype of datetime, date, and time.

I used the following query to find the list of tables:

```
select so.name table_name ,sc.name column_name ,st.name data_type
from sysobjects so
inner join syscolumns sc on (so.id = sc.id)
inner join systypes st on (st.type = sc.type)
where so.type = 'U'
and st.name IN ('DATETIME', 'DATE', 'TIME')
```

Is it possible to modify the query so that I can find the max date for each record?  Can I declare a variable to take the column names in the list and apply the max() function to them?

Comment: Why don't you try that variable thing with something simple?

Comment: I think you should go with Dynamic sql using sp_executesql: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using your original query and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @sql = STUFF((
    SELECT    'UNION ALL SELECT ''' + so.name + '.' + sc.name + ''', MAX([' + sc.name + ']) FROM [' + so.name + '] '
    FROM      sys.sysobjects so
    INNER JOIN sys.syscolumns sc ON (so.id = sc.id)
    INNER JOIN sys.systypes st ON (st.xtype = sc.xtype)
    WHERE     so.type = 'U' AND
            st.name IN ('DATETIME', 'DATE', 'TIME')
    FOR
    XML PATH('')
), 1, 9, '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You might benefit from reading up on the following:

- [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178107.aspx)
- [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188043.aspx)
- [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: That's nice. I'd use UNION ALL instead of UNION though.

Comment: In doing so, I've noticed that join between `syscolumns` and `systypes` is incorrect. Instead of joining on `type` this should be `xtype`.